# Как объединить два идентичных метода проверки типа данных в один?

Tags: c#, типы-данных

Прошу помощи в следующем вопросе:
Есть два метода, которые проверяют корректность введенных данных, один проверяет значения `double`:

```
public static double InputValidationDouble()
        {
            double i;
            while (true)
            {
                if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
                    return i;
                else Console.WriteLine
                        ("Ошибка ввода, введите значение еще раз");
            }
        }
```

Другой типа `int`:

```
public static int InputValidationInt()
        {
            int i;
            while (true)
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
                    return i;
                else Console.WriteLine
                        ("Ошибка ввода, введите значение еще раз");
            }
        }
```

Можно ли объединить их в один метод?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, например с помощью ООП

Интерфейс парсера

```
public interface IParser<T>
{
    bool TryParse(string input, out T result);
}
```

Парсеры

```
public class DoubleParser : IParser<double>
{
    public bool TryParse(string input, out double result)
    {
        return double.TryParse(input, out result);
    }
}

public class IntParser : IParser<int>
{
    public bool TryParse(string input, out int result)
    {
        return int.TryParse(input, out result);
    }
}
```

Ваш метод

```
public static T InputValidationDouble<T>(IParser<T> parser)
{
    T i;
    while (true)
    {
        if (parser.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
            return i;
        else Console.WriteLine
                ("Ошибка ввода, введите значение еще раз");
    }
}
```

Пример вызова

```
InputValidationDouble(new DoubleParser());
```

---

Ну, или делегаты

```
public delegate bool MyTryParse<T>(string input, out T result);
```

Ваш метод

```
public static T InputValidationDouble<T>(MyTryParse<T> parser)
{
    T i;
    while (true)
    {
        if (parser(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
            return i;
        else Console.WriteLine
                ("Ошибка ввода, введите значение еще раз");
    }
}
```

пример вызова

```
InputValidationDouble<double>(double.TryParse);
```